# Applescript to add grandparent folder+parent folder prefix to filename

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, automator

I have multiple folders with sub folders that have files in them that need to be labeled with their parent folder+grandparent folder name.

i.e. Folder 1>Folder 2>File.jpg needs to be renamed to Folder_1_Folder_2_File.jpg

I was able to find a script that somewhat does it, and have been trying to reverse engineer it, but am not having any luck.  The script below presents two challenges, 1) It includes the entire path from the root directory, and two, it deletes the name of the file, therefore only allowing one file to be renamed before it errors out.  I know that the problem is that the script is renaming the entire file, I just don't know how to proceed.

```
tell application "Finder"
set a to every folder of (choose folder)
repeat with aa in a
    set Base_Name to my MakeBase(aa as string)
    set all_files to (every file in aa)
    repeat with ff in all_files
        set ff's name to (Base_Name & "." & (ff's name extension))
    end repeat

end repeat
end tell

to MakeBase(txt)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set new_Name_Raw to every text item of txt
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_"
    set final_Name to every text item of new_Name_Raw as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return final_Name
end MakeBase
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFolder to do shell script "sed 's/\\/$//' <<< " & quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)
set myFiles to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & quoted form of myFolder & " \\! -name \".*\" -type f -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2")
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    tell application "System Events" to set file aFile's name to (do shell script "sed 's/.*\\/\\([^/]*\\)\\/\\([^/]*\\)\\/\\([^/]*$\\)/\\1_\\2_\\3/' <<< " & quoted form of aFile)
end repeat
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but Brian can't learn anything about AppleScript from it. If his needs change, he won't be able to reverse engineer this, and he'll be back to SO with another question.

Comment: Brian will learn more about the capabilities of AppleScript from this than he will from your answer.

Comment: No, he might learn about shell scripts, if he can read this at all. This teaches him nothing about how to use AppleScript with another app like iTunes or Safari.

Comment: `*\\/\\([^/]*\\)\\/\\([^/]*\\)\\/\\([^/]*$\\)/\\1_\\2_\\3/' <<< ` is about the most obtuse piece of code I've seen on SO.

Comment: It was obviously more helpful than your answer to him ... he accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with theItem in (the selection as list)
        set theItem's name to (theItem's container's container's name) & "_" & (theItem's container's name) & "_" & (theItem's name)
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you want to learn how AppleScript can work with an app, look through the app's dictionary of AppleScript commands (AppleScript Editor > File > Open Dictionary...).

*Edit 1*

Here's a version in which you select the "grandparent folder" containing folders containing the items to rename:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set itemsToRename to {}
    set selectedFolders to (the selection as list)
    repeat with selectedFolder in selectedFolders
        set childFolders to every item of selectedFolder
        repeat with childFolder in childFolders
            set grandchildItems to every item of childFolder
            set itemsToRename to itemsToRename & grandchildItems
        end repeat
    end repeat

    repeat with theItem in itemsToRename
        set theItem's name to (theItem's container's container's name) & "_" & (theItem's container's name) & "_" & (theItem's name)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I want to be able to select the grandparent folder and pass the rules to all the files in the subfolder, how can I modify this action to do that?  I was able to get this to work, but only at the file level.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rather than just the files, this script will re-name any directories that may exist in the subfolders. http://i.imgur.com/TcfAzw6.png

Comment: @adayzdone , Brian didn't how to handle folders that exist in the same directory as his example JPEG files. If he doesn't want to rename folders, he can change `every item of childFolder` to `(every item of childFolder whose kind is not "Folder")`.

Comment: or (every file of childFolder)